# For some reason I cant see the overrides option in the inspector section of my object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

[image]
So what im trying to make right now is a mobile game while following a tutorial on how to do so. I've already encountered a problem which is the fact that I can't see prefabs and overrides options in the inspector section of my player(the sheep). Usually, in the top part of the inspector, under "Tag" and "Layer" you have an option for prefabs and overrides, but I don't for some reason.I pasted the whole image so you can view where the object is located, and hopefully, help me solve this problem

EDIT: So I have solved that problem thanks to Iggy, but now I have another problem sadly :(, which is the fact that whenever I click on overrides, it doesnt show a button called "Apply all", it just says "No overrides", does anyone know why?

Comment: Maybe because you're in Play mode?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I apologize for my lack of intelligence. You have solved my greatest problem, you see, I'm very new to this so I have no idea what anything does, and I am relying on the Youtuber to explain things for me. Again, Thank you very much.

Comment: OH wait, now I have another problem :(... when I click overrides its supposed to show a button called "Apply All", but all it says is "No overrides", do you know why?

Comment: That just means you have no changes on prefab that need applying.